# Interacting esp8266 with LPC link2 on LPC XpressO instead of Arduino

Tags: c, lpc

LPC 4370 link2 to interact with huzzah esp8266 breakout board. I am using LPC XpressO, but all the codes available are from Arduino. Tried changing the codes from to suit my programmer.  WiFi.begin(SSID, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) but I do not know how to replace these codes with as there is not a wifi function from my microcontroller.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context as to what you're attempting to do, so we can better understand the problem?

Comment: i want to interface my LPC link2 chips with esp8266 via uart, however the problem is that i do not know how to create a esp8266 library codes that suits my LPCXPRESSO. there are only arduino examples on the web. i need codes that can be used on LPCXPRESSO.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to write your own esp8266 library. I done that for arduino once because I disliked the native arduino library since it blocked the device while searching for hotspots.

Try to study ESP8622 AT-Commands (they are few), and you will be able to implement what you want in no time, without any library dependencies.

Comment: i had more or less finished learning at commands, but the problem is that i do not know how to write my own LPCXPRESSO library using at commands. pls advice thxs ! there isnt any example codes other than arduino, i need an example for LPCxpresso